# factor sudo across pipes

Tags: pipe, sudo

I have this command line

```
$ sudo find /etc/grub.d | sort | tail -n 1 | xargs sudo cat | wc
```

that I want to execute with a single sudo command

```
$ sudo --some-how "find /etc/grub.d | sort | tail -n 1 | xargs cat | wc"
```

such that the entire command line is run as root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo sh -c "find /etc/grub.d | sort | tail -n 1 | xargs cat | wc"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do so far, but I am hoping for something less hack-like

```
$ echo "find /etc/grub.d | sort | tail -n 1 | xargs cat | wc ; exit" | sudo -iE
```