# How do you remove configuration settings from debconf

Tags: debconf

I've tried this approach mentioned in many places, but it fails with the following error message:

sudo echo PURGE | debconf-communicate mirrorsync
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that sudo is no longer effective after the pipe character so the subsequent command is not as root.

See [Pipe command with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292676/pipe-command-with-sudo) and [factor sudo across pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569627/factor-sudo-across-pipes).

Comment: I ended up giving up on debconf, but thank you for this answer.